# Express & res.render passing the template as string

Tags: express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I would like to perform the res.render, but instead of passing the template file as parameter like this:

```
res.render('index.hbs', { a: 'B' });
```

I would like to be able to pass the template as a string like that:

```
let template = '{{ a }}'
res.render(template, { a: 'B' });
```

The code above is obviously not working since res.render accepts only file path/name. Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render your template first

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');

// set up your handlebars template
var source = '{{ a }}';

// compile the template
var template = handlebars.compile(source);

// call template as a function, passing in your data as the context
var outputString = template({ a: 'B' });
```

and then send the output to the client

```
res.send(outputString);
```